# How can I add an InnerShadow and a transparent background to a Polygon in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a script that draws a game board of hexagon shaped tiles.  I want to add an InnerShadow effect to each tile but I also want each tile to have a semi-transparent background.  The normal shadow should be on top of the transparent background(if that makes sense).  For some reason unknown to me, the shadow shows up as artifacts.  If I remove setFill from the tile, it automatically has a black background.  In the screenshot, the little white dots are what I am referring to as artifacts.  What am I doing wrong?

### **Update**

After further investigation, I realized that the white dots are actually part of the image.  But the problem of the InnerShadow not showing up remains.  So I have changed the title of the question.  How can I add an InnerShadow and a transparent background to my polygon?

```
private void drawHexGridLoop(GraphicsContext g, Point origin, int size, int radius, int padding, boolean blank) {

    String rsrc;

    double ang30 = Math.toRadians(30);
    double xOff = Math.cos(ang30) * (radius + padding);
    double yOff = Math.sin(ang30) * (radius + padding);
    int half = size / 2;

    int i = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {

        int cols = size - java.lang.Math.abs(row - half);

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

            int xLbl = row < half ? col - row : col - half;
            int yLbl = row - half;
            int x = (int) (origin.x + xOff * (col * 2 + 1 - cols));
            int y = (int) (origin.y + yOff * (row - half) * 3);

            Hexagon hex = new Hexagon(x, y, radius);
            int diceNum = diceSpaces.get(i);
            if(!blank){
                rsrc = resources.get(i);
            } else {
                rsrc = null;
            }
            //hex.draw(g, x, y, diceNum, rsrc);    
            Polygon tile = new Polygon();
            for(int p = 0; p < hex.xpoints.length; p++){
                double xpoint = hex.xpoints[p];
                tile.getPoints().add(xpoint);
                double ypoint = hex.ypoints[p];
                tile.getPoints().add(ypoint);
            }
            tile.setFill(Color.web("rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)"));
            InnerShadow innerShadow = new InnerShadow(5, Color.WHITE);
            innerShadow.setOffsetX(4);
            innerShadow.setOffsetY(4);
            tile.setEffect(innerShadow);
            wrapperPane.getChildren().add(tile);
            tiles[i] = new Tile(i, xLbl, yLbl, rsrc, diceSpaces.get(i), hex.xpoints, hex.ypoints);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe the white dots are coming from the background video-image when it is below a transparent-like-white exagon ? Try with one other background image to see the result.

Comment: I suggest you provide a [mcve], including the picture you use so we can isolate the cause. Just remember not to paste the whole program you have - only the necessary parts so that we can run and see.

Comment: How should I add the images?  Just Imgur URLs?

Comment: That would work, but better yet load the image in the code from the URL so we don't need to save and reference to it loaclly.

Comment: Can I just upload the entire project to dropbox?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you but no one will look at it. Code should be in the question and should be a [mcve], and not the whole project. No one wants to read 90% code which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Also, use `@` to reply in comments.

Comment: See the update I made to the OP.

Comment: Unfortunately, the transparency you apply to the background is also applied to the innershadow. So if your background has opacity of 50% then an innershadow of 100% opacity will appear with 50% opacity. Not sure if that's a bug or a feature, but it would explain why your opaque white shadow isn't noticeable on top of a semi-transparent white background.